# "Badzipfile: file is not a zip file" using os and openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, openpyxl

I have a folder with a bunch of excel spreadsheets (directory called "path" here) and I need to extract a cell from each of the files (same location) and paste it in a new spreadsheet (calling it "output" in the code). I've used the openpyxl module because I can't change the file format into csv and I was struggling to get panda to work. Using os module to iterate through each document in the directory.

This is my code:

```
import openpyxl
import os

output = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"output file location")
osheet = output.active

path = "directory location"

os.chdir(path)

x=1
for i in os.listdir():
    address = "%s\%s" % (path,i)
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(address)
    sheet = wb.active
    unl_vol = sheet['i3'].value
    
    osheet ['B' + str(x+1)].value = unl_vol
    osheet ['A' + str(x+1)].value = str(i)
    x=x+1
    output.save("output file location")
```

This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\m0s0yin\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 16, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(address)

  File "C:\Users\m0s0yin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,

  File "C:\Users\m0s0yin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)

  File "C:\Users\m0s0yin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')

  File "C:\Users\m0s0yin\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1266, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()

  File "C:\Users\m0s0yin\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1333, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

I thought it might be a problem with the dash on the definition of "address" but I've tried either way. The code worked for a single file, it's when I added the os module and the for loop that it broke.

Comment: Add a `print(address)` to your loop to see if it's getting the desired files.

Comment: It looks like it is getting the desired files

Comment: From the traceback, I'd ask are the Excel files the modern XML type with extension 'xlsx' or the older binary 'xls' type. Openpyxl can only read the OOXML supported 'xlsx' file which is a zipped file. If the file(s) is the correct type then try unzipping it yourself with winzip or whatever your default archive app is. You should be able to unzip the file and obtain the individual XML files (and others) that make up the Excel file.

Comment: Other notes though not related to your issue; it may be better to use os for your path since you imported it and it manages different OS so **address = "%s\%s" % (path, i)** would be written as **address1 = os.path.join(path, i)**. Also for increment  you can just do **x += 1** rather than **x=x+1** or you could also use enumerate for x so the value gets incremented automatically on each loop i.e. **for x, i in enumerate(os.listdir(),1):** initialises x with value of 1 and on each loop x increments by 1 so the x += 1 is not needed.